# jQuery.Cycle Offsets Images On Certain Refreshs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm having a hard time understanding what is causing my jQuery script to load correctly on first load (clicking navigation link), but then fail upon hitting "refresh" in the browser.

It's a simple script to cycle through a series of images, full-sized and centered within a fluid layout. Upon load, the script should set an appropriate margin-left for the images, as to center it on the screen. When you click on the link in the navigation, it seems to work. When I refresh the page, the script fails, and gives the images a margin-left double what it should be, offsetting the photos off to the side of the screen.

The slideshow can be seen in action here. You should be able to replicate the error by refreshing the page, then hitting the blue "tiburon residence" link in the navigation. (Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4fnt.jpg)

http://dev.christinerode.com/garyhutton/tiburon.html

I've tried changing the order of my script and CSS includes, as well as the functions, but I'm having no luck. Why would this only happen on certain refreshes?

Using the jquery.cycle plugin, but can't find any other occurrences of this. What's happening in the javascript to trigger different displays of the same code?

Comment: It's not the only case. The other bug is that if someone fast-clicks the 'next' button it happens!

Comment: And I don't even need to click on 'tiburon', it's a matter of case: Try to hit a couple of times CTRL+F5 - in 1/3 cases the positioning fill fail .

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

place ALL your scripts before the `</body>` tag. That way you make sure the document is loaded before your DOM elements sizes measuring take place:

```
  <script> // jquery // </script>
  <script> // cycle.plugin </script>
  <script> // your jQ functions // </script>

</body>
```

Than you could add an `if` statement to check if your slide is animated to prevent clicks while the gallery is animating:

```
$("#slide_prev").click(function(){
   if( !($('.slideshow img').is(':animated') ) ){
      $('.slideshow').cycle("previous");
   }
});
$("#slide_next").click(function(){
   if( !($('.slideshow img').is(':animated') ) ){
      $('.slideshow').cycle("next");
   }
});
```

That will prevent the issue in my comment on your *Question*.

If you still have errors (what I don't suggest but you can try is):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // your functions
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Roko! Moving all the javascript to right before the </body> tag did unfortunately not work. However, wrapping everything in `$(window).load(function(){` did seem to work perfectly. What is the downside to just keeping it like that? What would any other solutions be?